# 9F1D is it a configuraiton or derived from other config

Tags: emv, mastercard

When checking a payment app static config I found something I consider a divergence.

```
<ttq>A2000000</ttq>
<term_caps>E06808</term_caps>
<txn_tag_data>9f1d082CB8000000000000</txn_tag_data>
```

which is sent to kernel during a CTLS transaction as:

```
9F3303E06808 -> SET 004000 (Byte 2 Bit 7) Enciphered PIN for online verification
9F6604A2000000  -> NOT SET 040000 (Byte 1 Bit 3) Online PIN supported
9f1D082CB8000000000000 -> NOT SET (Byte 1 Bit 7) Enciphered PIN verified online (Contactless)
```

I couldn't find the information in EMV books if the tags must be consistent.
If enciphered online PIN is set in terminal capabilities shouldn't it be also set in TTQ and 9F1D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tags referred to different card schemes. Up to your terminal config if you need to enable/disable Online PIN with different card schemes requirements and between EMV Contact and Contactless capabilities.

Tag `0x9F66` used by some Card schemes. It is not always Terminal Transaction Qualifiers (TTQ). The meaning is different per scheme Kernel and not always used.
Check details in **EMV Contactless Specifications for Payment Systems** books.

Tag `0x9F1D` Terminal Risk Management Data defined in **EMV Contactless Specifications for Payment Systems, Book C-2, Kernel 2** which is MasterCard's PayPass.

It needs to be configured on terminal application at least for MasterCard Contactless related kernel initialization.
In the MTIP 2.0 Build 260 Test plan (current as of 2021) MasterCard also add EMV Contact cases MTIP65.* when terminal need to return this Tag value to the card for EMV Contact transaction withing CDOL1 data.